# Null date in java code when i run the web service from server

Tags: java, date

i have created a web service and the client send a file to the server. Then the server have to save the file. The name of the file i want to be something like message_2013.03.20.13.55.43.xml (yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm.ss). I deployed the web service but the files are saved like message_.xml (overwrites the files) which means that date string is null. 
This is the part of my code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String current_date = dateFormat.format(date).toString().replaceAll(":", ".");
current_date = current_date.replaceAll(" ", ".");
current_date = current_date.replaceAll("/", ".");;
String pathname = "C:\\soap_downloads\\message_"+current_date+".xml";
```

when i test it on my localhost it runs perfect. Server's operation system is windows 2008 R2.

Comment: Why do you have to use replaceAll() so many times, just remove these characters from the format itself. Let it be yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss, what say?

Comment: Why do you use that date format string when you later replace all the characters? You could simply use `yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss` instead!

Comment: Just print the current_date before you create pathname, see what you get there?

Comment: If the date string was null you would not get `message_.xml` (You'd get `message_null.xml`)

Comment: The formatted date in your case is not `null`. According to your explanation it is empty.

Comment: The problem is that when i deploy the web service from localhost everything look perfect and the files are saved, but when i deploy it in server i cant get the current_time.

Comment: You 're right it is empty. But i can't imagine why it is empty!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you just *see* file name as `message_` and its icon is probably like icon of `xml` files. Windows file manager probably just hides extension from you. It probably thinks that everything after the first dot is extension and hides this part of the file name from you. Since you are using dots into file name it is possible. Try to double check this first.

Comment: thanks for the response, but why windows overwrite the files? When i deploy it from localhost the files are saved perfect

Comment: in that case though, it would still be message_2013. since the year is part of the name, not extension. It looks like the date is not being substituted.